# Nested query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Im having problem getting a nested query working with elasticsearch (If i remove one of the query-strings it works). the problem I am trying to solve is that i have a document (Closure) containing a list of closures. And I want to search for a value in the list of closures where another value is meet by a condition. That is only take value from a closures where argan=1

```
{"query":{
  "bool":{
     "must":[
        {
           "nested":{
              "query":{
                 "query_string":{
                    "default_field": "closures.rating",
                    "query": "5"
                 },"query_string": {
                    "default_field": "closure.argang",
                    "query": "1"
                 } 
              },
              "path":"closures"
           }
       }
     ]
  }
}}
```

Im getting this error-response;

```
     {
      "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards       failed; shardFailures {[O3wmPzFbTY6VkgvJOchpBQ][bransch_test][2]: SearchParseException[[bransch_test][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\":{\n      \"bool\":{\n         \"must\":[\n            {\n               \"nested\":{\n                  \"query\":{\n                     \"query_string\":{\n                        \"default_field\": \"closures.rating\",\n                        \"query\": \"5\"\n                     },\"query_string\": {\n                        \"default_field\": \"closure.argang\",\n                        \"query\": \"1\"\n                     } \n                  },\n                  \"path\":\"closures\"\n               }\n           }\n         ]\n      }\n   }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[bransch_test] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[O3wmPzFbTY6VkgvJOchpBQ][bransch_test][3]: SearchParseException[[bransch_test][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\":{\n      \"bool\":{\n         \"must\":[\n            {\n               \"nested\":{\n                  \"query\":{\n                     \"query_string\":{\n                        \"default_field\": \"closures.rating\",\n                        \"query\": \"5\"\n                     },\"query_string\": {\n                        \"default_field\": \"closure.argang\",\n                        \"query\": \"1\"\n                     } \n                  },\n                  \"path\":\"closures\"\n               }\n           }\n         ]\n      }\n   }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[bransch_test] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[O3wmPzFbTY6VkgvJOchpBQ][bransch_test][4]: SearchParseException[[bransch_test][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\":{\n      \"bool\":{\n         \"must\":[\n            {\n               \"nested\":{\n                  \"query\":{\n                     \"query_string\":{\n                        \"default_field\": \"closures.rating\",\n                        \"query\": \"5\"\n                     },\"query_string\": {\n                        \"default_field\": \"closure.argang\",\n                        \"query\": \"1\"\n                     } \n                  },\n                  \"path\":\"closures\"\n               }\n           }\n         ]\n      }\n   }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[bransch_test] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[O3wmPzFbTY6VkgvJOchpBQ][bransch_test][0]: SearchParseException[[bransch_test][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\":{\n      \"bool\":{\n         \"must\":[\n            {\n               \"nested\":{\n                  \"query\":{\n                     \"query_string\":{\n                        \"default_field\": \"closures.rating\",\n                        \"query\": \"5\"\n                     },\"query_string\": {\n                        \"default_field\": \"closure.argang\",\n                        \"query\": \"1\"\n                     } \n                  },\n                  \"path\":\"closures\"\n               }\n           }\n         ]\n      }\n   }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[bransch_test] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[O3wmPzFbTY6VkgvJOchpBQ][bransch_test][1]: SearchParseException[[bransch_test][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\":{\n      \"bool\":{\n         \"must\":[\n            {\n               \"nested\":{\n                  \"query\":{\n                     \"query_string\":{\n                        \"default_field\": \"closures.rating\",\n                        \"query\": \"5\"\n                     },\"query_string\": {\n                        \"default_field\": \"closure.argang\",\n                        \"query\": \"1\"\n                     } \n                  },\n                  \"path\":\"closures\"\n               }\n           }\n         ]\n      }\n   }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[bransch_test] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }]",
      "status": 400
     }
```

My mapping looks like this.

```
{
"closure": {
  "properties": {
     "name": {
        "type": "string"
     },
     "closures": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
           "argang": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "rating": {
              "type": "string"
           }
        }
     },
     "coadr": {
        "type": "string"
     },
     "telnr": {
        "type": "string"
     }
  }
}
}
```

Annyone have any idea on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is not a valid query. You need to use a proper compound query to combine other queries together, you can't just use a comma and add another query where only one is supported.

You can for instance use a bool query and have two must clauses, pretty much your two query_string. Or maybe you can even switch to using filters, and have a filtered query.
I'd have a look at the examples on this article: http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/.